# Is Running Bitcoin Core (bitcoind) On Android Termux A Good Idea?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, full-node, validation

This is what I did:

Before we begin, disable Google Play services and Google Play store to reduce conflict with app on F-Droid.

Decentralization gets us even further with what I figured out.

Install F-Droid.apk and verify with GPG && install F-Droid.

Update F-Droid repository and search for Termux.

Install Termux. Open termux and type setup-termux-storage

Grant Termux access to storage.

Do the following commands:

pkg install update

pkg install upgrade

pkg install openssl

pkg install openssh

pkg install proot

pkg install bitcoin

cd

Optional: if you want to copy your bitcoin folder from your pruned bitcoin (I have 2200mb prune) server or computer and prune it, fine (location: cd .bitcoin)
bitcoind -prune=2200

Recommended: On Termux notification on Android, enable
acquire wakelock and disable battery optimisation for Termux. Also, in router virtual server/port forwarding, Enable TCP port 8333 to 8333 for yur phone's ip address.

Note: during initial sync, it can cause silicon degradation so it is recommended to get a recent (within 3 months of blocks) pruned and try on your pc first (linux) before copying blockchain files to .bitcoin folder in termux. As long as you keep blockchain within 3 months, your phone is not stressed. Let's decentralise BTC more! :)

Proof: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rI9tE.jpg
[image: Snapshot of Bitcoind running in Termux Android]

Am I doing it right?